# Identically Distributed Functions of Random Variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

How can you tell if two functions of random variables are identically distributed. For example,

$Y_{1} = 2X_{1}$ and $Y_{2} = X_{1} + X_{2}$

How does one determine whether they are identically distributed?

I know that they are identically distributed $ \iff P(\{Y_{1} \in B\})=P(\{Y_{2} \in B\})$
for ever B Borel Set of $R$, but I don't know how to apply this.

Answer (score 1):

If you have $f_{X_1}$ and $f_{X_2}$ , one way to do it is to calculate the distributions of $f_{Y_1}$ and $f_{Y_2}$ and compare them.

If $Y=g(X)$ and $g^{-1}$ exists, then:
$$
f_Y(y) = f_X\left(g^{-1}(y)\right) \left| \frac{d g^{-1}(y)}{d y} \right|
$$
Also, if $Y=U+V$, then $f_Y$ is the convolution:
$$
f_{Y}(y) = \int f_U(t)f_V(y-t)dt
$$
($Y = y$ whenever $U = t$ and $V = y-t$, so that $U + V = y$).

In your example, $f_{Y_1}(y) = \frac{1}{2}f_{X_1}\left(\frac{y}{2}\right)$, and $f_{Y_2}(y) = \int f_{X_1}(t)f_{X_2}(y-t)dt$.

---

#### Discrete Random Variables

If the random variables are discrete, the same formulas apply, but the distributions will contain [Dirac delta](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function) functions (which are not real functions), so it's much easier to compare the actual probabilities than the distributions.

In your example:
$$\begin{align}
P(Y_1=y) &= P(X_1=y/2)\tag{1}\\
P(Y_2=y) &= \sum_t P(X_1=y-t)P(X_2=t)\tag{2}
\end{align}$$
Then just compare $(1)$ and $(2)$. You can also calculate $(2)$ using [stars and bars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28combinatorics%29).

- Example: If $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent and identically distributed, with $50\%$ chance of being $0$ and $50\%$ of being $1$, then:
  $$\begin{align}
  P(Y_1=0) &= 1/2\\
  P(Y_1=1) &= 0\\
  P(Y_1=2) &= 1/2\\
  P(Y_2=0) &= 1/4\\
  P(Y_2=1) &= 1/2\\
  P(Y_2=2) &= 1/4
  \end{align}$$

Comment: Thank you! Then, the two RVs in this example are not identically distributed then, correct?

Comment: Well, you can still pick specific $X_1$ and $X_2$ so that $\frac{1}{2}f_{X_1}\left(\frac{y}{2}\right) = \int f_{X_1}(t)f_{X_2}(y-t)dt$. But usually $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ won't be identically distributed. If it were discrete, you could think of $Y_1$ as rolling a die and multiplying the result by $2$, whereas $Y_2$ is like rolling two dice and adding the results.

Comment: So, how would I show that two discrete random variables were identically distributed or not? Sorry for pushing for so much detail. Just want to clarify for each usual type of random variable.

Comment: I updated the answer with the discrete case.